# jQuery Mobile site with multiple files

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile-friendly website using jQuery Mobile but would like to do it using multiple HTML files, each with one data-role="page" div (instead of multiple data-role="page" divs in one file as seems to be the standard), because this allows for maximum reuse of the existing site. I know the whole data-ajax="false" concept that I could use on the main page's `<a>` tags, but that disables the page transition effects, which we really like.

I've tried pageshow, pagebeforeshow, pageinit, document.ready, etc. but none of that ever fires unless I go to that page directly, as opposed to following a link from the main page i.e. the TOC (or refreshing the page after following a link from the TOC).  So basically, my JS file looks like:

`('div[data-role="page"]:first').live('pageshow',function(){ /*do custom stuff here */})`

I also tried adding the reference to this JS file onto the TOC page but no luck ... which I kind of expected but I figured I'd try.  I find it hard to believe that JQM simply doesn't support doing the site this way (without losing the transition effects), so I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: What version of Jquery and Jquery Mobile are you using?

Comment: It hit me soon while I was re-reading my question right after submission, then I tried it out and confirmed my suspicion ... the problem was with my selector ... div[data-role="page"]:first selects the first page div of the TOC page if I'm following a link from the TOC. So I started using IDs on my divs ... which I should've been doing all along anyway ... and it started working!

Comment: Well I'm glad you figured it out. Jasper's answer is an important thing to look at. There are some known issues with live. Also id's do work alot better. If your using Jquery 1.7.x use the .on() method instead of live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.live()` is depreciated, so use `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
2. You should bind to IDs rather than using multiple pseudo-selectors (I think this is your problem, that your complex selector may not be valid for event delegation):

.

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    //you can now do work for the `#my-page-id` pseudo-page
});
```

If you want to bind to all of the pseudo-pages to do something globally you can use:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {
    //you can now do work for all the `[data-role="page"]` "pages"
});
```

Or you could put classes on the different `data-role="page"` elements to specify which one you want to bind to.

Comment: It hit me soon while I was re-reading my question right after submission, then I tried it out and confirmed my suspicion ... the problem was with my selector ... `div[data-role="page"]:first` selects the first page div *of the TOC page* if I'm following a link from the TOC.  So I started using IDs on my divs ... which I should've been doing all along anyway ... and it started working!

Comment: Guess that's exactly what you were saying hehe, so I marked this as an answer (in my excitement I didn't read through all of the posts here) ... though now I have a new problem, it only works for the first page loaded from the TOC, each separate file has "next" and "previous" navigation buttons and when I use those I'm having a similar problem, any idea why?  But if I go to a page from the TOC then click on that page's TOC and go to the next page from there it's fine ...